# Java-MyBatis with HQL/other generic SQL engine or an API to convert SQL

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, mybatis, activiti

I am working on a project which uses Activiti[1](http://activiti.org/) Library and, for these reason, I am using MyBatis API to execute some native queries against Activiti data base.

The problem is: For some builds I am using Oracle and, for other, MySQL database then, as the dialect of this two data bases is different, it would be necessary to use the MyBatis multi vendor support, however, I didn't like it, because I have to deal with specific statments of each type of data base which makes the maintance a hard task, mainly if necessary to add another data base in the future.

So I would like to know if somehow it is possible to use HQL together with MyBatis or if there are another generic SQL engine that can be used in this case.

Or if someone know a free Java API that converts MySQL queries to Oracle queries. I tried to use Hibernate translation, however it didn't work, because Activiti classes is not using JPA, so it is not mapped :(.

Thanks in advance!

Sandro

Answer (score 1):

In Activiti, we do use the multi-vendor support of MyBatis. However, there are only a few cases where we really needed. Do you have that much 'special' queries?

Comment: Hi @Joram Barrez, 
Thanks for your answer,

In fact I don't have that much of 'special' queries, however for me and for the team, it would be a little bit hard to maintain if we have to map the diferences, but I think that this is really the only solution.

In Activiti do you use XML approach to map the specific diferences among data bases? As I am using anotations, I would like to know if  there is another way to do that by using Java Classes.